# Odoo7 float field with precision

Tags: odoo

I type 1,000,000,000,000 in amount field. It is auto add .000122 after save.

1,000,000,000 is ok.

Why? Please anyone help me?

Thanks...

Here is my field:
'amount':fields.float('Amount',digits=(12,6))

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8fNs.png)

Comment: the 6 are the precision, you want two? put 12,2

Comment: No, I want 6 precision. May be it is because of floating point issues and limitations, Right? What should I do?